# Ask Google not to crawl my Plesk login form

Tags: cpanel, vps, plesk, google-crawlers

I have some sites hosted on my Virtual Private Server. Plesk's URL is like this : https://myVPS_IP:8443

But it's also available from my sites url : https://mysite1.com:8443, https://mysite2.com:8443 ... and Google shows this URL in result page !

How can I disallow Google to crawl Plesk's URL ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have installed plesk panel on your server and google will not crawl your plesk panel URL with the port. But if you want to disable is for your site folder and pages then you need to update your robots file,

Please have look at : http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html

Comment: Hello, could you please support me at creating documentation for Plesk at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/plesk/commit